# Elixir / Phoenix: How to customize HTTP request log format?

Tags: logging, elixir, phoenix-framework

By default, my Phoenix apps log basic information about each HTTP request across ~ 5 lines of log output. As long as I've set my log level to `:debug`, I can see each request's method, path, controller & action, params, response code, and duration:

```
2019-06-14 16:05:35.099 [info] GET /manage/projects/7qDjSk
2019-06-14 16:05:35.103 [debug] Processing with RTLWeb.Manage.ProjectController.show/2
  Parameters: %{"project_uuid" => "7qDjSk"}
  Pipelines: [:browser, :require_login]
2019-06-14 16:05:35.116 [info] Sent 200 in 17ms
```

That's a great starting point. But I'd like to customize the app to log all of this info on one line, which is helpful eg. when sifting through large amounts of log output in a tool like [Papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/). In particular I'd like each request to show up in a format like this:

```
[PUT /manage/projects/74/prompts/290] params=%{"project_uuid" => "74", "prompt" => %{"html" => "<div>Test question 3</div>"}, "prompt_uuid" => "290"} user=38 (Topher Hunt) status=302 redirected_to=/manage/projects/74 duration=423ms
```

In [the Phoenix.Controller docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#module-options) I see I can configure the log level for the Phoenix controller logging, or disable it altogether, but I don't see a way to customize the format. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't a matter of customizing output, rather it's a matter of 1) disabling the default request-related log statements (by detaching the relevant `:telemetry` handlers) then 2) adding a new plug to log the format I want.

Here's how I did it:

- In `application.ex`, in the `start/2` function, detach the telemetry handlers that Phoenix attaches for you by default. (Call `:telemetry.list_handlers([])` to see all attached listeners.)

  ```rb
  def start(_type, _args) do
    # ...

    # vvv ADD THESE vvv
    :ok = :telemetry.detach({Phoenix.Logger, [:phoenix, :socket_connected]})
    :ok = :telemetry.detach({Phoenix.Logger, [:phoenix, :channel_joined]})
    :ok = :telemetry.detach({Phoenix.Logger, [:phoenix, :router_dispatch, :start]})

    # ...
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  ```
- In `lib/my_app_web/endpoint.ex`, comment out the `Plug.Telemetry` plug.
- In `lib/my_app_web/endpoint.ex`, add this custom plug just before Plug.Session:

  ```rb
  # One-line request logging. Must come before the session & router plugs.
  plug MyAppWeb.RequestLogger
  ```
- Finally, add `lib/my_app_web/plugs/request_logger.ex`. (Adjust the details accordingly; this implementation assumes the logged-in user struct is stored in `conn.assigns.current_user`):

  ```rb
  # One-line full request logging inspired by Plug.Logger.
  # See https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/v1.8.0/lib/plug/logger.ex
  # Need to restart the server after updating this file.
  defmodule MyAppWeb.RequestLogger do
    require Logger

    @behaviour Plug

    def init(opts), do: opts

    def call(conn, _opts) do
      start_time = System.monotonic_time()

      Plug.Conn.register_before_send(conn, fn(conn) ->
        # We don't want passwords etc. being logged
        params = inspect(Phoenix.Logger.filter_values(conn.params))

        # Log any important session data eg. logged-in user
        user = conn.assigns[:current_user]
        user_string = if user, do: "#{user.id} (#{user.name})", else: "(none)"

        # Note redirect, if any
        redirect = Plug.Conn.get_resp_header(conn, "location")
        redirect_string = if redirect != [], do: " redirected_to=#{redirect}", else: ""

        # Calculate time taken (in ms for consistency)
        stop_time = System.monotonic_time()
        time_us = System.convert_time_unit(stop_time - start_time, :native, :microsecond)
        time_ms = div(time_us, 100) / 10

        Logger.log(:info,
          "■ method=#{conn.method} path=#{conn.request_path} params=#{params} "<>
          "user=#{user_string} status=#{conn.status}#{redirect_string} duration=#{time_ms}ms"
        )

        conn
      end)
    end
  end
  ```
- Restart your server, and you should now see just one log line per request, formatted like this:

`2019-06-09 18:18:51.410 [info] ■ [PUT /manage/projects/7qDjSk/prompts/3tUrF9] params=%{"project_uuid" => "7qDjSk", "prompt" => %{"html" => "<div>Test question 3</div>"}, "prompt_uuid" => "3tUrF9"} user=1 (Topher Hunt) status=302 redirected_to=/manage/projects/7qDjSk duration=21ms`

(Note: Another, more best-practice approach would be to `:telemetry.attach` to the `[:phoenix, :router_dispatch, :stop]` event that Phoenix is already emitting. This provides all the data we'd need; see [the Phoenix.Endpoint docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#module-instrumentation) for more detail.)

Useful references:

- https://hexdocs.pm/logger/1.8/Logger.html
- https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/v1.8.0/lib/plug/logger.ex
- https://www.verypossible.com/blog/thoughtful-logging-in-elixir-a-phoenix-story
- https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/o17nfvwzbo--list-all-telemetry-event-handlers

Answer (score 0):

There is also this one, in case you want JSON output: https://github.com/Nebo15/logger_json/tree/master/lib/logger_json